# How to detect when an animation has ended roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a script designed to make an npc in my game do the default roblox idle animation but once Animation2 starts, it doesn't end, how can I fix this?

```
local idle1 = script.idle.Animation1
local idle2 = script.idle.Animation2

local animator = script.Parent.Humanoid.Animator

local LoadedIdle1 = animator:LoadAnimation(idle1)
local LoadedIdle2 = animator:LoadAnimation(idle2)

local function PlayAnimation()

    local roll
    local animation

    roll = math.random(1, 10)

    if roll == 1 then
        animation = LoadedIdle2
        LoadedIdle2:Play()
    else
        animation = LoadedIdle1
        LoadedIdle1:Play()
    end

    animation.KeyframeReached:Connect(PlayAnimation)
end

PlayAnimation()
```

I tried adding animation.Ended:Connect(PlayAnimation) but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there are a few events that an [AnimationTrack](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/AnimationTrack) will fire at different times.

- [KeyframeReached](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/AnimationTrack#KeyframeReached), which fires every time playback of an AnimationTrack reaches a Keyframe that does not have the default name - "Keyframe."
- [Stopped](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/AnimationTrack#Stopped), which fires whenever the AnimationTrack finishes playing.
- [Ended](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/AnimationTrack#Ended), which fires when the AnimationTrack is completely done moving anything in the world. The animation has finished playing, the "fade out" is finished, and the subject is in a neutral pose.
- [DidLoop](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/AnimationTrack#), which fires whenever a looped AnimationTrack completes a loop, on the next update.

It sounds like you want the Stopped event.

```lua
local function PlayAnimation()
    local roll = math.random(1, 10)
    local animation = if roll == 1 then LoadedIdle2 else LoadedIdle1

    animation:Play()
    animation.Stopped:Wait()

    PlayAnimation()
end
```

Comment: I didn't connect to the Stopped event because nothing ever disconnected the event and I was worried this would leak connections over time. However, my solution may cause a stack overflow after enough loops. A simple work around may be to `spawn(PlayAnimation)` to start a new callstack for the next time the function runs.